# How can I scale faces without moving them?

Tags: scale

I'd like to scale all outer faces of an object without making it smaller.
[image: My problem]
So in this case I want to make the selected faces thinner(scale them on the x and y axis), but WITHOUT being moved to their origin.
Or in other words: want them to scale to their own origin instead of being scaled to the objects origin.

Of course I could scale each of them individually, but that's a real grind and I wonder, if said thing is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use *"individual origins"* pivot option:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Change the Pivot to Individual origins.

<kbd>S</kbd>  to scale. and hold down  <kbd>Shft  + Z</kbd>  while scaling to confine to X and Y axis.

[image]